# How can I set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

I know this is a really simple question, but after searching a lot I can't find how to set headers.

Here's what I want to do:

Whenever the user goes to https://www.google.com/, then an extension should log that into a logfile.  I currently am developing the extension on my own device, and using `http://localhost/log.php` to get POST requests and log information to files based on the information POSTed.  My manifest is working and I have tested it.  Below is my `track.js`:

```js
function log(info){
    var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(this.readyState===4&&this.status===200){
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhttp.open("POST","http://localhost/log.php",true);

    // xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    // above: my first attempt to set a header (did not work)

    xhttp.send("log_info="+info);
}
if(location.href==="https://www.google.com/")log("We're at google.com!");
```

This is my `log.php`:

```php
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
if(isset($_POST["log_item"]))
    file_put_contents("log.txt", $_POST["log_item"]."\n",FILE_APPEND);
```

And `log.txt` is an empty file.  I know CORS is the problem because when I open the console on https://www.google.com/, I see this:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/log.php' from origin 'https://www.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

POST http://localhost/log.php net::ERR_FAILED
```

This seems really simple to me but I can't find how to set headers.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: The code you've provided will not cause that error. If you *uncomment* the line above "above: my first attempt to set a header (did not work)" then it would, but you shouldn't try to put a response header on the request.

Comment: No. **do not** uncomment the first attempt. **the first attempt is completely wrong**. The code you **have** won't cause the problem you say it will. The problem is **caused** by your first attempt.

Comment: @Quentin: Oh OK.  So how do I fix it / how do I set the request header?

Comment: **DO NOT** set the **request** header. There is no CORS request header (except `Origin` which the browser will set automatically)

Comment: @Quentin: But if I comment out the PHP try and the JS try, then I still get the error above.

Comment: Shocking! If you do the thing I said you should not do because it causes the problem then the problem happens!

Comment: @Quentin: I uncommented the PHP one and kept the JS one commented and it didn't give any error, but nothing was logged.  I *think* the header problem is fixed but it still doesn't log anything.

Comment: Nothing being logged is a completely different problem to the one you asked about (and is because you failed to set the content-type request header)

Comment: @Quentin: OK, the problem is solved, I guess.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" on your webserver configuration (Nginx or Apache or ...) that you are currently using on your localhost.

You can not bypass CORS from your code or your request at all.

For nginx (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf):

https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Apache:

https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

Comment: "You should add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" on your webserver configuration" — They have. We can see it in the PHP code in the question.

Comment: Setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` won't fix this problem because (aside from it already being set) the error is: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: First of all, that's exactly what I'm trying to do but I don't know how.  Second, I'm trying to do that but it isn't working (the code is in my question).

Comment: Allow-Origin MUST set on webserver side not in your request header.

Comment: @APB: Thanks for the links.  Sorry I didn't see them earlier.  I've accepted your answer because your solution worked.  (Also, I did bypass CORS because of that `header` in my PHP, but that was only for that single file).

Comment: Your welcome :) And once again, CORS is a security policy for preventing attacks like CSRF. We can't bypass a server security policy by adding one header to our request to that server. If you want to disable or config this policy you should submit changes on server-side configurations. I hope it has been clear for you now.